# How to delete duplicates pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I need to check if there are some duplicates value in one column of a dataframe using Pandas and, if there is any duplicate, delete the entire row.
I need to check just the first column.

Example:

```
object    type

apple     fruit
ball      toy
banana    fruit
xbox      videogame
banana    fruit
apple     fruit
```

What i need is:

```
object    type

apple     fruit
ball      toy
banana    fruit
xbox      videogame
```

I can delete the 'object' duplicates with the following code, but I can't delete the entire row that contains the duplicate as the second column won't be deleted.

```
df = pd.read_csv(directory, header=None,)

objects= df[0]

for object in df[0]:
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885093/how-do-i-remove-rows-with-duplicate-values-of-columns-in-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select by duplicated mask and negate it

```
df = df[~df["object"].duplicated()]
```

Which gives

```
   object       type
0   apple      fruit
1    ball        toy
2  banana      fruit
3    xbox  videogame
```

Answer (score 0):

use [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method

```
d = pd.DataFrame(
    {'object': ['apple', 'ball', 'banana', 'xbox', 'banana', 'apple'],
    'type': ['fruit', 'toy', 'fruit', 'videogame', 'fruit', 'fruit']}
)
d.drop_duplicates()
```

there are several keyword args. that might come in handy (like `inplace=True` if you want your dataframe `d` to be updated)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `subset='object'` to select the column you want to check, as follows:

```
df_out = df.drop_duplicates(subset='object')
```

Result:

```
print(df_out)

   object       type
0   apple      fruit
1    ball        toy
2  banana      fruit
3    xbox  videogame
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the length after dropping duplicates

```
df = len(df)-len(df.drop_duplicates())
```